# How to change a specific character with another character in a text document with python?

Tags: python

I have a python code which is able to open and write in a file. But I want to replace every "d" in my document with some other character. So how to do that with python ?

Comment: HI, Welcome to SO. Could you please share some code snippet ?. tell us what you have tried and issue you are facing so that we can help. I would recommend to go over this doc - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask question on stack overflow.

Comment: @Masklinn although the syntax is the same in Python, you are linking a Javascript question.

Comment: Thanks for replying , I am new to SO and yes i will repost this question with the code.